# JQuery error after joomla 3.8.10 update

Tags: jquery, kunena

Hello I get this jquery error after my last kunena update to 3.8.10: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).insertAtCaret is not a function". You can see the complete error in the following capture:
[image: capture]

This error occours when users try to insert attached files to a kunena post. Attaching files does work good, but insert the file doesn't.
I have checked a new template and this new template solves the problem. Obviously there is a incompatibility problem between Joomla 3.8.10 and my template. However, I would like to keep this old template, because it has a lot of customization I wouldn't like to lose.
Could you help me to solve this jquery error in order to keep this template?
I promise I will not update joomla for a long time :(

EDIT: more info, mi site loads jquery 1.12.4

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can we have a link to your site? If not, which template are you using? Are you loading multiple jQuery versions?

Comment: Yes, of course, this is a direct link to forum:

http://www.f1losdominguitos.com/index.php/foro/categorias

You can use this temporal user, don't need to register:

User: test
Password: 12345678

You can see the problem inserting files to a post. Feel free to create a new post if necessary. My template is JSN Megazine 1.1.0.

Many thanks.

Comment: You're loading 3 instances of jQuery. No doubt the error is caused by this. I don't have access to this template as it appears to be commercial so I don't know which line to look for

Comment: The template is comercial, but is a free version. Here you have it. It is the template my site is using right now: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lx3kowVMWxoLunqmEGvRCPG-YtdSe-BF

Answer (score 1):

To fix jQuery issues on Joomla I will suggest you use [jquery Easy](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy/)

It provides options to load  jQuery and other Js as per your requirement also it removes all unnecessary js. Must try.